# Android paypal sdk Integration : Server communication error on the sandbox account

Tags: android, paypal

> E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:Certificate pinning failure!
>
> Peer certificate chain:
>   sha1/SQ+EdYjo3ZoEORzSEC2JQV3g3L4=: CN=api-m.paypal.com,OU=CDN Support,O=PayPal\, Inc.,L=San Jose,ST=California,C=US
>   sha1/UCM4nF92oH7yVEZeTyGW+BRFtB4=: CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4,OU=Symantec Trust Network,O=Symantec Corporation,C=US
>
> Pinned certificates for api-m.sandbox.paypal.com:
>                                                                          sha1/u8I+KQuzKHcdrT6iTb30I70GsD0=
>   sha1/7Q3I1izTEynYgv4tw/zFENNNuxQ=
>   sha1/sYEIGhmkwJQf+uiVKMEkyZs0rMc=
>   sha1/gzF+YoVCU9bXeDGQ7JGQVumRueM=
>
> 01-21 13:04:51.999 20902-20902/sprittle.com.sprittle E/paypal.sdk: SERVER_COMMUNICATION_ERROR

[image]

Comment: please format your question and include your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Version 2.13.0](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/releases) of the PayPal Android SDK should fix the issue.

[PayPal sandbox recently upgraded to only allow TLS 1.2](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1914&expand=true&locale=en_US) and made other pre-emptive security updates ahead of PCI compliance requirements. You can find out more details at the [InfoCenter microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1914&expand=true&locale=en_US).

Answer (score 2):

try this change your paypal sdk version

android studio change in gradle

is old paypal sdk : PayPalAndroidSDK-2.11.2.jar 
to change add new paypal sdk : compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1'

eclipse 
add new paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1.jar file and bulid

Comment: i want to get payment order information .can you help me?

Comment: hey,,i want to get this parameter information of completed order.
payment_status 
transaction_type (txn_type)
txn_id
seller_paypal
seller_id
payer_id
payer_name
payer_status

Comment: can you please give method of "orderPaymentDetail();"?