# request failed with server response:null, SERVER_COMMUNICATION_ERROR, Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, paypal-sandbox

I am using the following Plugin in Cordova (android) : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

The plugin was working fine few days ago. But now I'm getting this error in logcat. And getting following error while I'm running my app :

There is a problem communicating with the PayPal servers . Please try again.

Is this issue in Paypal server or any mistake from my end?

Comment: is there anyone who can answer this question?

Comment: Check out the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917885/android-paypal-sdk-integration-server-communication-error-on-the-sandbox-accou/35238463#35238463